# react - onchange of select option unable to call another react component from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**I have created a component and called to API to load the data and trying to call another component on change of select options**
First Drop down is getting populated on screen but on change of second we are not able to render it and getting error in console like second component is not present

```
const e = React.createElement;

class DownloadCenter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            productDownloadList : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        debugger;
        $("#select_productLine13").select2();
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8082/abc/support/pqr/getProductLines',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {}

        })
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response)
                /*#__PURE__*/

                this.setState({productDownloadList : response.data.productLineDTOList})

            })
            .catch(
                error => {
                    console.log(console.log(error))
                }
            );

    }

    render() {
        debugger;

        const {productDownloadList} = this.state
        let productDownloadList1 = productDownloadList.length > 0 && productDownloadList.map((item, i) => {
            return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("option", {
                key: i,
                value: item.productLineId
            }, item.productLineName);
        }, void 0);

        return React.createElement("div", {
            class: "fl"
        }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("select", {
            id: "select_productLine13",
            name: "selDataVal",
            onChange: this.aa

        }, productDownloadList1));
     }


}

$("#select_productLine13").on("change", function () {

    debugger;
    console.log("anc")
    /*#__PURE__*/
    React.createElement(DownloadCenter1, null);

})
```

**DownloadCenter1 component **

```
 "use strict";
const e = React.createElement;

class DownloadCenter1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            productDownloadList : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        debugger;
        $("#select_productLine13").select2();
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8082/abc/support/pqr/downloadCenter/productNames',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {}

        })
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response)
                /*#__PURE__*/
                this.setState({productDownloadList : response.data.productLineDTOList})
            })
            .catch(
                error => {
                    console.log(console.log(error))
                }
            );

    }

    render() {
        console.log("inside");
        return ;
        //return React.createElement("div", {value: "Hi"});
        /*#__PURE__*/
        //React.createElement(DataTable, {
        //    title: "Desserts",
        //    selectableRows: true
        //});
    }

}

export default DownloadCenter1 ;
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#select_productLine112');

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

root.render(e(DownloadCenter1));
```

Comment: please use code sections in your post. At the moment the code is not readable.

Comment: Done... please advise